# why does my glutWireSphere not fill in with color?

Tags: opengl, colors, glut

I am trying to make a basic animation that has a 'blimp' float across the window.  I have tried adapting different tutorials and sources to help build my code so be easy on the critique.  Im still figuring it out.  My main question is why does my glutWireSphere not fill in with its specified color?  Just the outline is visible.  Let me know any suggestions.  Code is below.

```
#include <stdlib.h> // need to include for non keywords like NULL
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h> // open gl wrapper class

GLfloat speedX = 0.01; // blimp's speed in x & y position
GLfloat speedY = 0.001;
GLfloat blimpX = 0.0; // blimp's (x,y) position
GLfloat blimpY = 0.0;
GLfloat blimpXMax, blimpXMin, blimpYMax, blimpYMin; // blimp's bounds

class Blimp {

    public:
    void draw(void);
};

void Blimp::draw(void)
{
    glPushMatrix();
        glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);
        glutWireSphere(8, 25.0, 25.0);
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-8, 0,0);
        glutWireSphere(6, 25, 25);
        glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();
}


void display()
{

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix(); // save modelview matrix
    Blimp blimp;
    glTranslatef(blimpX, blimpY, 0.0); // move blimp
    blimp.draw();
    glPopMatrix(); // restore modelview matrix
    glutSwapBuffers();

    // compute location for next refresh
    blimpX += speedX;
    blimpY += speedY;

    //check if blimp exceeds edges: return on other side
    if (blimpX > blimpXMax + 14) {
        blimpX = blimpXMin - 14;
    } else if (blimpX < blimpXMin - 14) {
        blimpX = blimpXMax + 14;
    }
    /*  
    // check if blimp exceeds edges: bounce back other direction
    if (blimpX > blimpXMax) {
        blimpX = blimpXMax;
        speedX = -speedX;
    }   else if (blimpX < blimpXMin) {
        blimpX = blimpXMin;
        speedX = -speedX;
    }
     */

    if (blimpY > blimpYMax) {
        blimpY = blimpYMax;
        speedY = -speedY;
    }   else if (blimpY < blimpYMin){
        blimpY = blimpYMin;
        speedY = -speedY;
    }


}


void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-50.0, 50.0, -50.0, 50.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    blimpXMin = -50.0 + 14;
    blimpXMax = 50 - 8;
    blimpYMin = 25;
    blimpYMax = 50 - 8;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`glutWireSphere` draws a *wireframe* sphere. You want `glutSolidSphere`.

See: http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node81.html

Comment: i tried that and the outline is more faint than with the wireSphere and still does not fill with color. any other ideas?  i have used the glutSolidSphere in other cases and it fills.